# jQuery: How to get text of current tag using id?

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to send ajax GET-request with jQuery and I need to send the id of an entity to the controller. I am using *thymeleaf* `th:each` looping for displaying entities. The code that I have written is working for the first entity but not for others.

Following is HTML page code:

```
<div th:each="course : ${session.courses}" >
        <img th:src="@{'/images/' + ${course.image.imageURL}}" alt="">
        <h3 class="text-dark" id="course-id" th:text="${course.courseId}" style="display: none;" ></h3>
        <h3 class="text-dark" th:text="${course.courseName}"></h3>
        <p class="mt-3 mb-4 pl-lg-4" th:text="${course.title}"></p>
        <a th:text="${course.courseDuration}"></a>
        <a th:text="${course.noOfSets}"></a>
        <a class="btn button-cour-w3ls text-white" th:href="@{'course_details?cid='+${course.courseId}}" role="button">Learn More</a>
        <a class="btn bg-dark text-white" id="apply-course"  role="button">Apply Now</a>
</div>
```

And this is jQuery code:

```
$("#apply-course").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var courseId = $("#course-id").text();
    var data="/?cid="+courseId;
    $.ajax({
        url : "/course/apply_course/"+data,
        type : "GET",
        success : function(result){
            if(result.status){
                alert("Data transfer successfull");
            }
            else{
                alert(result.message);
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Please add the errors you are getting.

Comment: The first issue is that you cannot have the same ID for multiple tags i.e, `id="course-id" `. This is the reason you always getting the same element each time.

Comment: Jazakallah @ Zaheer Ahmed issue is resolved I got the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying an id `id="apply-course"` which occurs multiple times due to your loop.
Try using a class instead.

```
<h3 class="text-dark" **class**="course-id" ...
...
<a class="btn bg-dark text-white" id="apply-course"  role="button">Apply Now</a>
```

Then in your js:

```
$(".apply-course").click(function(e) { // .apply-course
e.preventDefault();
var courseId = $(this).parent().find('.course-id').text(); // $(this) instead of query id
...
```

Final note: Its called jQu**e**ry my friend :D

Comment: Thanks @Pilan from your answer but iam fetching id from another a teg not same tag.

Comment: Have a close look im fetching `this -> parent -> course-id` it is another tag, but same parent

Comment: It is working thanks @Pilan .And also thanks for correcting my spelling mistake(j@uery)